# Existing Event Driven Network Protocols

Tags: events, client-server, network-protocols, subscription

I am building a set of programs that consist of multiple clients and a single server.

The clients are frequently pushing small packets of data to the server, which will validate the information (returning an error if the data is invalid), and process the received information. The information may then incur the firing of events, which clients will be subscribed to, allowing for clients to be instantly (or as close as possible) notified (along with a small amount of data).

I have some ideas about how to do this, but I am trying to avoid creating a protocol of my own, mainly as I'm sure it would take forever and I would probably make a few errors. So I was wondering if there are any existing protocols that I could implement into my system that would provide such functionality.

The number of clients will initially be quite small, but will be growing over time to potentially include 1000's of clients (with their own subscriptions), and several front end servers (each one handling a subset of subscriptions) parsing the information back and forth with back end servers for improved capability.

So, if anyone knows of any existing protocols that implement these requirements and functionality, that would be fantastic.

**EDIT**

I am currently looking at the XMPP protocol, and the JXTA protocol suite (for reference, and implement with another language). Both seem quite good and provide the necessary connectivity, but I have not had the opportunity to test each of them out in my environment, or if they are even suitable for what I am attempting.

Additionally, some of the network clients will be outside of the local network and operating over WAN. Security is not so much of an issue, but I need to take into account the increase latency of this, and firewall rules (local to the connection that is hosting the application and ISP firewalls) that could be blocking certain ports or transport protocols (I have read some text that said that some ISPs where blocking UDP packets, but not sure of how wide this goes. I can do it at home, the office, mobile, friends houses, etc and have yet to experience it myself).

Comment: What languages are you willing to consider?

Comment: Any really, but language isn't so much of an issue as a networking protocol can be run with any language that supports the networking requirements

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if the following is not exactly what you're after but I am slightly confused by your use of the word 'protocol'. I understand a protocol to be a 'communication specification' only, where the implementation is left entirely to you. If that is the case I always find the the following graphic usefull, [link](http://infothread.org/Internet/Guide%20to%20Communication%20Protocols.png).

If on the other hand you are looking for a solution which allows you to easily implement the networking side of your application, helping save time, then checkout the following network libraries, which implement their own custom protocol:

1. [NetworkComms.Net](http://www.networkcomms.net/adding-network-functionality-to-any-net-application-in-3-lines-of-code/)
2. [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/Basics)
3. [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for NetworkComms.Net

Comment: Yup, that is my interpretation of 'protocol' too, a specification that I can either implement or build a library for that can do what I am looking for. The implementation of networking is a relatively simple job, but I need a pattern to follow that can achieve what I am trying to do